# Responding to tile map collision in java

Tags: java, dictionary, 2d, collision, tile

I was just wondering, what is the best way to respond to 2d tile map collision in java.

I have the code setup so that when the Players Rectangle intersects with a Tiles Rectangle, which is part of a 2d array of Rectangles (Rectangle[][] collRects), the collision happens.

I know how to set that up, but when i run the program and the Player collides with a tile, the Player moves along the edge of the inside tiles and eventually goes through the collision Rectangles.

The way i am responding to collisions right now is:

1. I check with if statements which side of the tile the player collided with.
2. The Player has a speed variable, so i set to a value of zero on whatever axis the player was moving on before the collision.

I guess what i am trying to say is, what is the best way to respond to a collision?

Help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks.

Comment: please provide more detail about the way your sprites move: do they move freely inside the map? do they move aligned to some sort of grid (pacman like)? how many sprites can you have posibly colliding at the same time? 10? 1000?

Comment: The player can move freely around the tile map.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, seems that you are interested in detecting collitions between the player (a sprite) and the tiles (instead of other free-moving sprites).

For that, some simple modular arithmetic should suffice to detect (from the upper-left (x,y) coordinates of the player) which tile is colliding in the map.

Assuming the map is composed of a matrix of tiles of NxM, numbered from 0...N-1 horizontally, and 0..M-1 vertically, and the tile size is 32x32 pixels then the colliding tile coordinate (i,j) is:

i = floor(player.x / 32);

j = floor(player.y / 32);